# Laravel File Upload not working in godaddy server

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Having trouble in uploading files in my `laravel` project. It's working fine locally but not working on the `godaddy` server. I have used the following method to store my file,

First method:

```
$image = $request->file('avatar_file');
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->avatar_file>getClientOriginalExtension();
$destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
request()->avatar_file->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
```

Second method:

```
$image = $request->file('file');
$imageName = time().'.'.request()->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->file('file')->storeAs('documents', $imageName);
```

I have created symbolic link for this working in local not in server.

Answer (score 2):

As you have hosted your Laravel app on a shared hosting platform, your app doesn't know the correct path to your public directory.

So, you need to define a function in your `public/index.php` file like this: (Paste it on top of your `index.php` file)

```
function public_path($path = '')
{
    return realpath(__DIR__)
        .($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$path : $path);
}
```

Defining this function here causes the helper function by the same name to be skipped, thereby allowing its functionality to be overridden. This is required to use a "non-standard" location for Laravel's "public" directory.

Now create a new service provider for your path:
`php artisan make:PublicPathServiceProvider`

In the `register()` function you need the code as:

```
public function register()
    {
        if (env('PUBLIC_PATH') !== null) {
            //An example that demonstrates setting Laravel's public path.
            $this->app['path.public'] = base_path().'/../'.env('PUBLIC_PATH');
        } else {
            $this->app['path.public'] = base_path().'/../public_html';
        }

        // Possible environment changes
        if ($this->app->environment() === 'local') {
        } elseif ($this->app->environment() === 'test') {
        } elseif ($this->app->environment() === 'production') {
        }
    }
```

Now, register this Provider with your app.
`config/app.php`

Under Providers add this:

`App\Providers\PublicPathServiceProvider::class,`

Last step, in your `.env` file, create a new variable:
`PUBLIC_PATH=/public_html`

You are good to go!!!

**Note:** Do not forget to check the path to where you have uploaded your Laravel app. (Above, it is assumed the path is *public_html*)

**Important:** After changing the configurations you might need to clear the cache:

`php artisan config:cache`

`php artisan cache:clear`